# Memory limit exceed when image resize when laravel by using image intervetion

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, image-resizing

I implemented image resize method for all existing product images.but it will gave error message like this

> production.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 86736576 bytes) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 86736576 bytes) at /home/httpd/htdocs/qa/ebeyonds_oos/api/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php:236)

exists image saved read from aws s3 bucket and read that content use in image resizing process.

foreach ($productImages as $productImage) {

```
$imgArray = $productImage->images;
foreach ($imgArray as $img) {
    $filePathDetails = pathinfo($img->saved_name);
    log::info($img->saved_name);

    $fileName = $filePathDetails['basename'];

    if (isset($filePathDetails['extension'])) {
        $extension = ($filePathDetails['extension']);
    } else {
        $extension = $img->ext;
    }


    $fileNameFullPath = $ImageJob['client_id'] . $product_folder . '/' . $fileName;
    $imageExist = $disk->exists($fileNameFullPath);

    $imageExtensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'];
    if ($imageExist) {
        if (in_array($extension, $imageExtensions)) {
            $OriginalImageContent = $disk->get($fileNameFullPath);
            if ($OriginalImageContent) {
                $im = imagecreatefromstring($OriginalImageContent);
                $originalWidth = imagesx($im) ?? null;
                $originalHeight = imagesy($im) ?? null;

                $listingImagePath = $ImageJob['client_id'] . $listingFolder . '/' . $fileName;
                $thumbImagePath = $ImageJob['client_id'] . $thumbnail_folder . '/' . $fileName; 
      
                if ($isSmallResize == 1) {
                    $this->imageResize($originalWidth, $originalHeight, $defaultSmallWidth, $defaultSmallHeight, $OriginalImageContent, $listingImagePath, $extension, $disk);
                }
                if ($isThumbResize == 1) {
                    $this->imageResize($originalWidth, $originalHeight, $defaultThumbWidth, $defaultThumbheight, $OriginalImageContent, $thumbImagePath, $extension, $disk);
                }
                Log::info("ProdcutHandler requestToResizeImage:: File Found");
            }
        } else {
            Log::info("ProdcutHandler requestToResizeImage:: invalid Extension");
        }
    } else {
        Log::info("ProdcutHandler requestToResizeImage:: File Not Found");
    }
```

There is image resize method using image intervation

Please kindly help to resolve this problem.Thank you

Comment: what about using `ini_set('memory_limit', -1);` at the beginning or use fixed set `ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');`

Comment: @bhucho that is not a viable solution. but issue occured when 
$OriginalImageContent = $disk->get($fileNameFullPath) line. If $fileNameFullPath 's file size exceed more than 10 error occured.

Comment: @bhucho your solution is perfect.Thanks for helping. Its happen due to Image Intervention library issue.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/interventionimage-memory-limit?page=1